# Debian 10 wifi connection with heavy delay (but no package loss)

Tags: debian, networking, drivers

```
$ PING www.debian.org(klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=19481 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=18474 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=17450 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=16426 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=15402 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=14379 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=13355 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=8 ttl=56 time=12331 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=9 ttl=56 time=11307 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=10 ttl=56 time=10283 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=11 ttl=56 time=9259 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=12 ttl=56 time=8235 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=13 ttl=56 time=7211 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=14 ttl=56 time=6187 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=15 ttl=56 time=5164 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=16 ttl=56 time=4140 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=17 ttl=56 time=3112 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=18 ttl=56 time=2092 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=19 ttl=56 time=1068 ms
64 bytes from klecker-misc.debian.org (2001:67c:2564:a119::148:14): icmp_seq=20 ttl=56 time=44.1 ms
^C
--- www.debian.org ping statistics ---
21 packets transmitted, 20 received, 4.7619% packet loss, time 384ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 44.100/9770.030/19481.037/5902.815 ms, pipe 20
```

Package loss is fine, but delay can sometimes reach 20 seconds.

Network card information:

```
description: Wireless interface
product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
logical name: wlp5s0
version: 32
serial: 74:40:bb:24:89:33
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.19.0-5-amd64 firmware=RM.4.4.1.c2-00057-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.xxx.x.xx latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

I'm using Debian 10(buster) with kernel version `4.19.0-5-amd64` and I had no problem using Debian 9 a few weeks ago. So it's definitely not a hardware issue.

So how do I fix this driver problem? Do I replace it or upgrade/downgrade it? (I have never tune a wifi driver before so I don't actually know how to do that.)

Comment: Notice that Debian 10 is an unstable version. I installed it myself some days ago, however, I do not use it as as productive OS. I keep using Debian 9, because it works. Debian 10 is mainly for testing purposes. Unless you are ready to invest your time and technical expertise in it, I would just drop it.

Comment: However, Debian 10 is in full freeze now, preparing for release. Regression bug reports are very useful, please file one by running `reportbug kernel`. See https://wiki.debian.org/DebianKernelReportingBugs for further information.

Comment: Also take into account that another wifi antenna near by, a closes door your hand on the palmrest of a laptop or even a microwave oven could cause dramatic wifi performances. As much as it's convenient, wifi is not a really reliable network solution.